# How to filter extension in photoLibrary UIimgaePickerController swift

Tags: swift, video, filter, uiimagepickercontroller, mp4

I only want in the library there are one types of video. Use default library. My app is currently taking images and videos from the application document directory using UIImagePickerController (.photoLibrary). I want to show just one video type .mp4

```
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices
import Photos
import UIKit

 class CameraLibraryTestViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        }

        @IBAction func bAction(_ sender: Any) {
            picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.mp4"] // filter extesion mp4 didn't work, 
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.delegate = self

            present(picker, animated: true)
        }
    }



    extension CameraLibraryTestViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
            viewController.navigationItem.title = "Jeri Library"
            picker.setEditing(false, animated: true)
            print("test or check: \(viewController.debugDescription)")
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
            let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

            if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("MOV"))! {
                print("MOV")
                dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EmojiReadViewController(), animated: true)
                }
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("MP4"))! {
                print("MP4")
                dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EmojiReadViewController(), animated: true)
                }
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("M4V"))! {
                print("M4V")
                dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EmojiReadViewController(), animated: true)
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Unknown")
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to use mediaType `[kUTTypeMPEG4 as String]` but it still doesn't work, which is in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` it's only for filters after selecting from the library.

If I use `kUTTypeMovie` it gets all the videos on local storage

Comment: did u solve it ?

Comment: @EssamMohamed is solved in 2018 , thanks


let _extension = posibleVideoURL.pathExtension.lowercased()                    
                    if _extension == "mov" || _extension == "mp4" {}

Comment: Where to write these lines ?

Answer (score -1):

This will display only videos

```
picker.mediaTypes = [ "public.movie"]
```

Comment: He asks for mp4 only videos !